# @RefreshScope not working with external config files

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I added the following dependencies in my pom so I could make use of Spring cloud

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

  <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Added spring-cloud.version as Finchley.RELEASE

This is the bean that I intend to refresh:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(ignoreUnknownFields = true,prefix="global")
@PropertySource(value = "${spring.config.location}")
@Getter
@Setter
@Validated
@RefreshScope
public class GeneralProperties {
    private String mode;
}
```

Accessing the bean in my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping
@RefreshScope
public class AppController {

    private static final AnalyticsLogger LOGGER = AnalyticsLoggerFactory
            .getLogger(AppController.class);

    @Autowired
    SimulatorRequestProcessor simulatorRequestProcessor;

    @Autowired
    GeneralProperties generalProperties;

    @ResponseBody
    @PostMapping(value = "/api/mock-getdata", produces = "application/json")
    public String fetchResponseBasedOnMode(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers,
            @RequestBody String request) {
        String response = null;
        LOGGER.info("color: "+color);
        switch (generalProperties.getMode()) {
         //code
```

Properties set in application config:

```
 spring.config.location=file:///var/lib/data/demo/config/generalConfig.properties
 management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=refresh
```

Unable to refresh the value of mode. Can someone point out the error in this code. My property files are in a folder that is not committed in git, so I am not making use of spring-cloud-config.

Comment: Finchley is no longer supported, can you try again with Hoxton.SR1?

Comment: Also PropertySource and RefreshScope are not needed on configuration properties beans. Refresh scope also not needed on controller

Comment: I am making use of Spring-boot 2.0.1 RELEASE, so the compatible Spring cloud version for that is Finchley

Comment: And something may have been fixed in the 11 releases since then.

Comment: Boot 2.0.x is also not supported anymore

Comment: Tried removing RefreshScope and triggered. Still facing the same issue. PropertySource is needed as I want to read property files from an external location. If I don't use it, the application fails to start.

Comment: Tried with Hoxton.SR1 and Spring boot version 2.2.4. Still facing same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in `src/main/resources/application.properties`

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

Run this program with this argument `--spring.config.additional-location=/tmp/application.properties`

```
package com.example.demorefreshscopeexternalfile;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.core.style.ToStringCreator;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableConfigurationProperties(DemorefreshscopeexternalfileApplication.MyProps.class)
public class DemorefreshscopeexternalfileApplication {

    @Autowired
    MyProps props;

    @RequestMapping
    public String message() {
        return props.getMessage();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemorefreshscopeexternalfileApplication.class, args);
    }

    @ConfigurationProperties("my")
    public static class MyProps {
        private String message;

        public String getMessage() {
            return this.message;
        }

        public void setMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return new ToStringCreator(this)
                    .append("message", message)
                    .toString();

        }
    }
}
```

contents of `/tmp/application.properties`

```
my.message=message from /tmp
```

view `http://localhost:8080`

`/tmp/application.properties` can be updated, the post to `/actuator/refresh` and view `8080` again and you will see updated values.

Built with boot 2.2.4 and Hoxton.SR1

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.4.RELEASE/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#common-application-properties for `spring.config.*` and their meaning.

Comment: Is /tmp/application.properties placed under classpath? Because my requirement is to make use of an external file and this approach does not work for that.

Comment: No it is not on the classpath. It's a Linux temporary directory